# Cannot complete realtime search query

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="searchForm" onsubmit="return false" id="searchField" ng-submit="" \">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" formControlName="search" (keyup)="updateQuery()"/>

      <li *ngFor="let product of querySearch | async">
        {{ product.name }}
      </li>

</form>
```

Formbuilder setup

```
this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
      search: ['', Validators.required],
    });
```

```
this.afs.collection<any>('name', ref => ref.where('name', '==', name));
```

I cannot seem to create this search bar. The idea is that for every change of the value of the input field, the firestore query is changed to search 'products/{id}' to retrieve all products whose name value is Brian. I can't seem to accurately create code that will populate li below the search field with relavent material from the query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated... should I subscribe to the input field content and then update the query from within the subscription body?

Comment: So there are a few missing pieces in the question. How are you storing the search response from your afs query, what is this `name` property that you have, and why is it not the same as the `search` property that you would end up having in your reactive form as a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a reactive form for this. Just using an `[(ngModel)]` would work just fine.

Here, give this a try:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="search" (keyup)="updateQuery()"/>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let product of results$ | async">
        {{ product.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

And in your Component Class:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  results$: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
  search = '';

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {}

  ...

  updateQuery() {
    this.results$ = this.afs.collection<any>("items", ref =>
      ref.where("name", "==", this.search)
    );
  }
}
```

**PS:** I'm trying to create a StackBlitz to demo the code but I'm having an issue with the firebase dependency installation. I'll update this with a demo as soon as it works out for me.

Comment: Thank you... I cannot upvote because of my reputation, but check marked it

Comment: No worries buddy. Glad I could help :)